# Intermittent error: AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute equipTemp

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I've been playing with this code for a day now to get the readout from my temp sensor.

Oddly, I get this error probably 4 out of 5 times I run this code:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Code-working-library
>   /Temp_and_window_working ds18b20.py", line 118, in 
>      app.equipTemp.set(round(read_temp(),1)) AttributeError: 'App' object has no 
>      attribute 'equipTemp'

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import glob
import time
import subprocess
import re
import sys
import time
import threading

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

#28-000005c6ba08
#28-000005c70f69
#28-000005c80eb9

#the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#sensors = ['28-000005c6ba08', '28-000005c70f69', '28-000005c80eb9']
sensors = ['28-000005c6ba08'] 

def read_temp_raw():
    catdata = subprocess.Popen(['cat',device_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out,err = catdata.communicate()
    out_decode = out.decode('utf-8')
    lines = out_decode.split('\n')
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_f




##############################################
###########  build window  ###################
##############################################




class App(threading.Thread):

    def _init_(self):
        threading.Thread._init_(self)
        self.start()
    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()
    def run(self):
        self.root = Tk() #Makes the window
        self.root.wm_title("Temperature Monitor") 
        self.root.minsize(200,100)

        leftFrame = Frame(self.root, width=200, height = 600)
        leftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

        Label(leftFrame, text="Equipment").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

        self.equipTemp = StringVar()



        Label(leftFrame, textvariable=self.equipTemp, width=8, justify=RIGHT).grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
        Label(leftFrame, text="deg F").grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

        self.root.mainloop() #start monitoring and updating the GUI


##############################################
###########  Start Loop    ###################
##############################################

print "starting app"


app = App()
app.start()


print "app started"


###########################################################
###################  Begin ds18b20 function  ##############
###########################################################



while True:



    for i in sensors:
        base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
        device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + i)[0]
        device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

        #print i, (read_temp())


        ##################################################
        ##################### END ds18b20 Function  ######
        ##################################################




    app.equipTemp.set(round(read_temp(),1))

    # Wait 30 seconds before continuing
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Show full error message, there is number of line with problem.

Comment: BTW: you need more `_` in name `_init_`. DO you need `Thread` ? Can't you use `tk.after()` ?

Comment: @furas    
sorry , my router died over the weekend....here is the full error code:   
  
  
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Code-working-library/Temp_and_window_working ds18b20.py", line 118, in <module> app.equipTemp.set(round(read_temp(),1)) AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'equipTemp' –

Comment: You have `_init_` with single `_` on both sides but it should be two `_` on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens intermittently, it sounds like a classic race condition. The code that is trying to access the variable is executing before the variable is set.

Tkinter isn't thread safe. While I don't know with absolute certainty that you can't access an IntVar in a separate thread, it's highly likely that you can't.

Since you're only reading (short?) text files (or text-file-like devices), I'm not sure you need to use threading. Assuming you can read any single sensor file in, say, 100ms or less, you don't need threading at all. Just use `after` to call a function periodically to read the sensor data.